# Challenging... I guess it's impossible to scrape this webpage

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape this page: https://icd.who.int/browse10/2016/en

The problem is that the contents of the page that I am trying to scrape can not be found in the page source.

For example, I am trying to scrape the menu from the left side of the page, navigation, under "ICD-10 Version:2016" > "I Certain infectious and parasitic diseases" > A00-A09 Intestinal infectious diseases. 
  (

A00 Cholera

A01 Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers

A02 Other salmonella infections

.
. 
 )

The problem is that all of this for some reason can not be found in the page source. so when I scrape it, I do not get this data at all.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

url = 'https://icd.who.int/browse10/2016/en'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

c=result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html5lib')
```

Comment: That data is probably loaded asynchronously after the page loads. You'll need to be able to execute the JavaScript that loads the data. Selenium can do that I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not impossible, just more difficult because the data are loaded asynchronously (as @Carcigenicate said in the comments). A request is made to the server to load the data and can be seen in the network tab of developer tools on google chrome. The method I'm using takes a while (due to all the requests) but it does work.

```py
import requests

chapter_url = 'https://icd.who.int/browse10/2016/en/JsonGetRootConcepts?useHtml=false'
chapters = requests.get(chapter_url).json()
chapter_IDS = [chapter['ID'] for chapter in chapters]

inner_section_names = []
section_url = 'https://icd.who.int/browse10/2016/en/JsonGetChildrenConcepts?ConceptId={}&useHtml=false'
for ID in chapter_IDS:
    sections = requests.get(section_url.format(ID)).json()
    section_IDS = [section['ID'] for section in sections]

    for inner_ID in section_IDS:
        inner_sections = requests.get(section_url.format(inner_ID)).json()
        temp = [inner_section['label'] for inner_section in inner_sections]
        inner_section_names.extend(temp)

print(inner_section_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using official APIs

https://icd.who.int/icdapi/docs/APIDoc-Version2.html

and some more detail on the swagger open API endpoints

https://id.who.int/swagger/index.html

Endpoints for retrieving ICD10 category info are listed in the link directly above. E.g.

```
GET /icd/release/10
```

Lists the available ICD-10 releases

```
GET /icd/release/10/{releaseId}
```

This endpoint returns basic information on the released version of ICD-10 together with the chapters in it

```
GET /icd/release/10/{code}
```

Lists the available ICD-10 releases for the requested category

```
GET /icd/release/10/{releaseId}/{code}
```

This endpoint returns information on the category together with its children categories

N.B. ICD10 and 11 are covered. They can be accessed via GET using `requests`. Register for access [here](https://icd.who.int/icdapi/Account/Register).

Note [some benefits](https://icd.who.int/icdapi/docs/APIDoc-Version2.html) listed:

> 1. Trying the API From this swagger URL, one can try the API by making requests and see the responses coming
> 2. Automatic client code Generation.There are several free and open source software which could generate client code in various
>      programming languages using the Open API documentation. This will make
>      consuming our APIs much easier in the programming language of your
>      choice.